# How to find the complexity of this nested for loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

I am a little confused about this `for` loop. Given a number n, we have to find how many times will the instruction execution.

```
int j = 0;
for(int p = 0; p < n*n; p++ )
{
    for(int q = 0; q < p; q++ )
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

My answer is `O(n^4)`. Is this answer correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the related sigma for the time complexity `T(n) = sum_{p = 1}{n^2} sum_{q=1}{p} (1) = sum_{p=1}{n^2} (p) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n^2 = n^2(n^2 + 1)/2 = Theta(n^4)`. So, your answer is right for the number of the instructions.

Comment: Are you sure? The inner for loop doesn't get executed fixed n times but q<p so it would be 0,01,012,0123 etc. I'm not so sure it's n^4 but I could be wrong

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak check the equation. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: That was the thing I was confused about because if it was smaller or equal I would be sure that it is O(n^4).

Comment: @Indriti there is not any difference! count of the instructions is the matter. So, `p` from `0` to less than `n^2`, has `n^2` number! Be careful about the `p` and `q` are started from `0`.

Comment: Thanks then, it was very helpful.

Comment: Yes in the terms of the big-O notation it doesn't matter. I got confused too. All good.